# CSRF Token from the controller

Tags: symfony, csrf, symfony-forms

I have a controller getting a form posted.

```
public function myPostAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('my_form', $my_object);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
#...
```

I can see my CSRF token posted as parameter

> my_form[_token] => lH38HTm5P0Cv3TOc4-9xi2COx-cZ670mpJ_36gR8ccI

I simply need to read it

```
$form->get('_token')
```

This tells me

> Child "_token" does not exist.

How can I get this token ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the workaround I'm going to use meanwhile:

```php
$token = $request->get($form->getName())['_token'];
```

I also noticed by chance that the `intention` used to generate the token is the form name

```php
$csrf = $this->get('form.csrf_provider');
$intention = $form->getName();
$token = $csrf->generateCsrfToken($intention);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
The last line should read = instead of == (but I cannot edit this because edit should be at least 6 characters :'()

Comment: As of 2.4 you'll need to use 'security.csrf.token_manager' instead. For the intention/intent you'll probably need "form" or "authenticate". You can see what the intention is in the session data, which should be under var/sessions and have a name equal to that of your PHPSESSION cookie value.

Answer (score 6):

Like @Pierre de LESPINAY said, it is possible to do it by retrieving Token Manager service.

This service can also be injected in your constructor like that :

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
...
public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager)
{
    $this->tokenManager = $tokenManager;
}
```

And used later like previously demonstrated :

```
$token = $this->tokenManager->getToken('myformname')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with:

```
$request->request->get('my_form[_token]');
```

If you didn't disable CSRF-protection it will be applied and validated automatically and you don't need to check it by self.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `_token` is not there, `my_form[_token]` is there. I'm using the automatic token handling successfully already, but I need to get this token explicitly for an issue of asynchronous document upload (to be able to gather it back at post time)